# Get data from Http request in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, parameters

I am sendin post request from jquery like this :

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "Save",
   data: { conr: conr ,expiry : expiry,settings : settings}
```

inside servlet , i am able to get parameters `(conr , expiry , settings)`
but the problem is that
the `settings` parameter contains serialized form data : like this :

```
high=true&ci=false&title=qTip+as+Button+Menu&private=true&email=abc@google.com
```

I know that i can use `string tokenizer` to get data but i want to make sure that- if their is any simple way or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org) and let [`URLEncodedUtils`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) parse it for you.

So you could just invoke `URLEncodedUtils.parse(yourString,Charset.forName("UTF-8"))` and you receive as return a `List<NameValuePair>` containing name and value associated elements. In this case something like: hight = "true", title = "qTip as Button Menu" and so on. And this all with the right decoded.

Comment: their are many options on apache link...like HttpClient HttpCore and HttpAsyncClient .......which one should i download ?

Comment: can you please paste the link of JAR

Comment: [here](http://mirror.softaculous.com/apache//httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.2.1-bin.zip), you will find JARs to be imported on lib folder

Comment: I am getting this error in eclipse....The type org.apache.http.NameValuePair cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files...i placed jar in system library in jre6

Comment: which JARs did you added to your project? at least httpclient and httpcore must be added.

Comment: ok i did that and their is one error left now....the parse method takes string and CHARSET as parameters and this is not valid then `URLEncodedUtils.parse(yourString,"UTF-8")`

Comment: you are right, you can use it like this: `URLEncodedUtils.parse(yourString,Charset.forName("UTF-8"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use split on the settings string with "&" as a regex.

Comment: and after it you have to decode it because values are still encoded, for example title=qTip+as+Button+Menu